# Como comparar um CEP dentro de um array com vários intervalos em PHP?

Tags: php, array, if

Eae pessoal!

Estou precisando de uma sugestão de como filtrar um CEP dentro de uma lista que vai possuir vários intervalos, se (IF) o CEP estiver dentro dessa lista, executar um HTML que possui algumas strings em PHP.

Basicamente o CEP de teste seria 33100-100
E na lista de CEP seria por exemplo:

```
01000-000...01599-999
02000-000...02099-999
08000-000...08099-999
06300-000...06399-999
00640-000...06499-999
```

Como o CEP 33100-100 não participa da lista, não apareceria nada.
Se tentássemos com o CEP 01099-999 ele aceitaria e executaria o HTML.

O problema é que a lista de CEP é relativamente bagunçada e possui vários intervalos diferentes. No momento já são 85 intervalos, e talvez aumente no futuro, então queria algo prático pra facilitar na inclusão de novos intervalos no futuro. Alguém tem alguma ideia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Penso que pode ser assim:

```
//cep a ser encontrado
$cep="03100-100";
//array com os intervalos dos ceps
$array=array(
    array("01000-000","01599-999"),
    array("02000-000","02099-999"),
    array("08000-000","08099-999"),
    array("06300-000","06399-999"),
    array("00640-000","06499-999")
);
//foreach para buscar dentro do array de intervalos
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    //$value assume o papel dos arrays contidos dentro do array principal, sendo assim o offset [0] para o inicio do intervalo e [1] para o fim
    if($cep >= $value[0] && $cep <= $value[1]){
        echo "bingo ".$key;
        break;
    }else{
        echo "desculpe cep não encontrado";
    }
}
```

Desculpe pela bagunça, foi apenas para você ter um ideia do que fazer. Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Obrigado! Deu certinho :D